# Non-blocking threading and 'stop thread' button in Tkinter

Tags: python, tkinter

I have a Tkinter program with a textarea in which a list of youtube urls can be pasted and a button beside it saying 'Download' which will download the videos at the urls to a folder on my computer. I'm using the pafy module to download the videos.

I have set this up so that when the button is pressed it starts a thread which runs the function to download the videos. I thought with threading that this would leave the program unaffacted but a few moments after I press the button, even though the videos are downloading fine, the program gets blocked, has a 'Not Responding' message at the top of the program and remains that way until the function stops running, successfully completing the downloads. In other words the program gets blocked by the running function/thread and has that little hourglass thing that disables any other clicking or interactivity with the program until the downloads are complete.

I also have a button beside the 'Download' button with 'Stop' on it to stop the downloads whenever its clicked. Obviously since the entire program is blocked, even with threads, while the videos download, the 'Stop' button can't be clicked.

Can anyone point out how to get the thread to work without blocking the program and how to run the 'Stop' button in such a case? Here's the code:

```
import pafy
from threading import Thread

def downloadvideos():
    textdata = text1.get('1.0', 'end-1c').splitlines()
    downloadlist=[]
    downloadlist1 = []
    downloaddict = {}
    for t in textdata:
        print t
        downloadlist.append(t)
        print downloadlist
        try:
            url = t
            video = pafy.new(url)
            best = video.getbest()
            title = video.title
            best.download(filepath=foldername)
            downloaddict[title] = url
        except Exception:
            sys.exc_clear()

def but1thread():
    global thethread
    thethread = Thread(target=downloadvideos, name='firstthread')
    thethread.daemon = True
    thethread.start()
    thethread.join()

def but1stop():
    thethread.running = False


button1 = Button(frame1, text="Download", activebackground="green", command=but1thread)
button1.grid(row=1, column=0, sticky=W, padx=(10, 0), pady=(20, 0))

button2 = Button(frame1, text="Stop", background="red", command=but1stop)
button2.grid(row=1, column=1)
```

Comment: ***"thethread.join()"***: <= This is blocking, remove it. Read up on [threading.Thread.join](https://docs.python.org/3/library/threading.html#threading.Thread.join)

Answer (score 0):

The calling `thethread.join()` will block the tkinter mainloop, so it should not be called.

To stop the downloads, you can make use of the `callback` option of `best.download(...)`.  Inside the callback function, check whether `Stop` button is clicked. If yes, then raise exception to stop the download:

```
def on_downloading(*args):
    if not thethread.running:
      print '\ncancelling ...'
      raise Exception('download cancelled')

def downloadvideos():
    textdata = text1.get('1.0', 'end-1c').splitlines()
    downloadlist=[]
    downloadlist1 = []
    downloaddict = {}
    thethread.running = True
    for t in textdata:
        if not thethread.running:
            break
        print t
        downloadlist.append(t)
        print downloadlist
        try:
            url = t
            video = pafy.new(url)
            best = video.getbest()
            title = video.title
            best.download(filepath=foldername, callback=on_downloading)
            downloaddict[title] = url
        except Exception as e:
            print e
            sys.exc_clear()
    print('download completed')

def but1thread():
    global thethread
    thethread = Thread(target=downloadvideos, name='firstthread')
    thethread.daemon = True
    thethread.start()
    #thethread.join()  # join() will block the tkinter mainloop
```